# Passing an optional parameter with a default value in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following constructor:

```
  constructor(@Optional() private config?: DefaultConfig) {
      this.config = config || new DefaultConfig();
  }
```

Is there any way to avoid doing `this.config = config || new DefaultConfig();`? What I want is to add the default value in the constructor's parameter? Something like this:

```
  constructor(@Optional() private config?=new DefaultConfig(): DefaultConfig) {}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have a problem with doing it in the function body as above?

Comment: I don't have any problem but since the language allows me to use default values, why not to use it?

Answer (score 2):

So I'm not familiar with Angular2, however in pure TypeScript, the following achieves your intention:

```
constructor(private config = new DefaultConfig()) {}
```

That is, if no config is passed, `this.config` will be a new `DefaultConfig`. It also ensures that the constructor parameter must be of type `DefaultConfig`.

Comment: No, that doesn't work on angular2 with optional parameters.
Error: Can't resolve all parameters for MyClassName.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the following?

```
constructor(@Optional() private config: DefaultConfig=new DefaultConfig()) {
  ..
}
```

**Note:** no more `?` before `:`